# How to parse JSON on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this uncaught syntax error. I am trying to parse JSON that is on Firebase and make it a Javascript object so that I can use it further but I am getting this error. Sorry I am newbie to Firebase and JSON. I hope I am making some sense. Kindly help!

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at match.js:5

match.js:

```
var object = JSON.parse(postdata);
```

try.js

```
    var fRef = firebase.database().ref('lostitem/').push().key;
    var updates = {};

    postdata = {
        nameL: Name,
        namesl: lastname,
        AGE: 30
    };
    updates['/lostitem/' + fRef] = postdata;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

JSON file:

```
"lostitem": {
    "-KbtQKV3gujL9WaEqdj_": {
        "AGE": 30,
        "nameL": "CAT",
        "namesl": "persian"
    }
}
```

Comment: `postData` is not a JSON string. It's just an object. You don't need to parse it.

Comment: sorry if i sound lame since I am new to programming. how can we make JSON java script object and use it for further functionality?

Comment: You can't make a "JSON java script object", because there is no such thing. There are JSON strings, which you parse into JavaScript objects with `JSON.parse`, or create from JavaScript objects with `JSON.stringify`, and then there are plain old JavaScript objects, which is what `postdata` is, which you just use as is.